# Compare entries in DataTable when comparison value repeats

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, backend

I have a problem comparing DataTable entries when the field I filter to select and compare repeats in the table.

There is a DataTable which looks like this:

| Place | Color | Animal | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | cat | 3 |
| 1 | red | bat | 3 |
| 1 | red | dog | 4 |
| 1 | red | dog | 5 |

I compare the entries by column `Animal` and in this example, there are 2 `dog` which have different `Amount`. My test fail because it tries to copmare a `dog` who has `amount 4` with  a `dog` who has `amount 5`. Do you know if I can specify somehow sorting? That it checks exactly by the order how it is in DataBase.

Maybe the selection of ActualPet can be modified somehow?

```java
MyDb actualPet = actualPets.stream()
                                                               .filter(actualP-> actualP.getAnimal().equals(expectedPet.getAnimal()))
                                                                 .findAny()
                                                                 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(errorMessage));
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `findAny` you'll get some item from the list. But since you're only filtering on `animal` there are more elements.

The simple way around would be to filter for all relevant properties of the expected value and then check if the resulting stream contains exactly one elements.

A slightly more complicated way would be to implement `hashcode` and `equals`.  Then you can use `actualPets.contains(expectedPet)`

However both mean you have to sort out a lot of semantics each time you're dealing with this. Which isn't great. So it would be a good idea to use an assertion library. There are a few out there but [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) is one to recommend.

For example:

```
// extracting multiple values at once grouped in tuples
assertThat(fellowshipOfTheRing).extracting("name", "age", "race.name")
                               .contains(tuple("Boromir", 37, "Man"),
                                         tuple("Sam", 38, "Hobbit"),
                                         tuple("Legolas", 1000, "Elf"));
```